# Adding Custom Button in Push notification

Tags: ios, iphone, button, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

I am looking for the solution to add the Button on Push notification.
I am not talking about showing alert on screen if aap is in background or active.
I am talking about when my app in not in background nor active and push arrives then that push must have a button showing on it.

I am talking about the push notification which shows in Notification center of iPhone.

When user tap the button then i will do some action in the app.
I have already added the button in push notification, but that button shows only when user swipe the push in Notification center. 
Now i want this button on the push notification.

Can someone tell how to show that button on push notification?

Comment: look for interactive push notification on google.

Answer (score 0):

Check the [Actionable push notification docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/declaring_your_actionable_notification_types). Probably missing some configuration on the app